# JAVA - Graphics2D determine possible move in a game based on mouseEvent

Tags: java, user-interface

I am developing a game based on mouse events, similar to this: [How to draw grid using swing class Java and detect mouse position when click and drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421708/how-to-draw-grid-using-swing-class-java-and-detect-mouse-position-when-click-and/15422801#15422801)

I'm currently stuck at the point where I am trying to determine if the block I am pointing to in a grid is allowed to move.

Comment: How is `possibleMove` obtained? (From a MouseEvent?) *"if the block I am pointing to in a grid"* And pointing to with the cursor you mean? Also, *"I tried to use allowedCells.contains(possibleMove); but that did not work."*, what do you mean it didn't work? We need some more details.

Comment: No one can help you until you post your mouseEvent

Comment: How can I determine if current BLUE cursor is within a range i.e. can be on green block only. I think I need to find index of current cell and then determine that that green block exists at current position?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is a Square class object representing possible move.

Comment: To be honest, that don't mean much.  How do you determine when a cell is painted green? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I uploaded my program for like 10 minutes, but do not want to keep here for too long so it should give  full details.. Anyway thats exactly what I want to know: How to determine whether cell is painted?  For now I am using separate list to store Square objects but do not know how to determine, would you give any hints or sample example?

Comment: Loop through the allowedCells and see if the Rectangle contains the MouseEvents point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if the mouse is within a "allowed" cell, you could modify you `MouseListener` to something like...

```
MouseAdapter mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {

    // detects when mouse was moved
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        int width = getWidth(); // gets screen resolution e.g. 640x 480
        int height = getHeight();
        // System.out.println(width + " x " +height );

        int cellWidth = width / columnSize; // size of the cell in pixels e.g 32x24
        int cellHeight = height / rowSize;
        // System.out.println(cellWidth + " x " +cellHeight );

        int column = e.getX() / cellWidth; // gets specific cell e.g. (14,14)
        int row = e.getY() / cellHeight;
        // System.out.println("col " +column + " " + row);

        // This is the x/y position of the mouse when the event
        // was triggered
        Point mp = e.getPoint();
        for (Rectangle cell : allowedCells) {
            if (cell.contains(mp)) {
                // Do what ever you want to do here...
            }
        }

        selectedCell = new Point(column, row); // point to represent xy location
        repaint(); // repaint forest
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. I found a tiny error: "if (allowedCells.contains(mp))"  should be replaced by "if (cell.contains(mp))"