# Java : How to visualize/plot two parameters relations with a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, data-visualization, relationship, visualization

I have a table with the following structure:

[relation, variable1, variable2]

I would like to visualize those relation over a triangular matrix, [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO5e1.png) but with any number of variables and not only 4. Is there any free java library to do so? any ideas on how to visualize it by my own?
I don't have any code yet, Just thinking about the idea and process of how doing it.

much appreciation to all :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a Swing framework that is natively provided by Java so you don't have to import any external library for this task.

I think painting this matrix (as in your link) is not difficult using Swing.

I find this discussion very useful for your case [How to draw grid using swing class Java and detect mouse position when click and drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421708/how-to-draw-grid-using-swing-class-java-and-detect-mouse-position-when-click-and)

Because it provides an example of painting a matrix.